# Python convert tuple of tuples with keys and values to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am getting this weird looking data. I want to convert it to a dataframe.

```
sales_data = 
Totalsales(product='y', 
sales=(
specificsite(product='y', sales_percent =70.0, location_zip='12345'), 
specificsite(product='y', sales_percent =11.0, location_zip='23456'), 
specificsite(product='y', sales_percent =45.0, location_zip='34567'), 
specificsite(product='y', sales_percent =10.0, location_zip='45678')))

df = pd.DataFrame(sales_data)
```

present outupt:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Totalsales' object is not iterable
```

Expected output:

```
df = 
     product  sales_percent   location_zip
0    y          70             12345
1    y          11             23456
2    y          45             34567
3    y          10             45678
```

Comment: What is `Totalsales`? It's undefined in the code provided.

Comment: Not sure what those data types are, but a good guess might be: `pd.DataFrame(sales_data.sales)`

Comment: @Mark They are just string characters, nothing more. So, `Totalsales` has no definition or value.

Comment: @MichaelRuth They are just string characters, nothing more. So, `Totalsales ` has no definition or value.

Comment: @Mark `pd.DataFrame(sales_data.sales)` actually worked. I was able to convert it to the dataframe. Thanks a ton.

Comment: You show some code, not data.  It contains a number of function calls, functions which we know nothing about..